# Passing API data from parent container to child component in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a React container with a number of child components. One of which is supposed to be a modal that will show the user their name which is fetched from a user data api in the parent container. I should be able to pass the user data into the child with a prop, but must be missing something, as the display name does not show in the input as the value.

**Parent Container**

```
class ParentContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      displayName: this.state.user.displayName
    }
    this.config = this.props.config
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    try {
      const userData = await superagent.get(`/api/user`)
      await this.setState({ user: userData.body })
      console.log(userData.body.displayName) <===logs out user display name
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Cannot GET user.`, err)
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='reviews-container'>
        <ReviewForm
          config={this.config} />

        <ReviewList
          reviews={reviews}
          ratingIcon={this.ratingIcon}
        />
        <DisplayNameModal
          config={this.config}
          displayName={this.displayName} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ParentContainer
```

**Child Component**

```
 class DisplayNameModal extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      displayName: this.props.displayName
    }
  }

  render (props) {
    const {contentStrings} = this.props.config

    return (
      <div className='display-name-container' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.bgImgUrl})` }}>
          <h2 className='heading'>{contentStrings.displayNameModal.heading}</h2>
          <p>{contentStrings.displayNameModal.subHeading}</p>
          <input type="text" placeholder={this.props.displayName}/>
          <button
            onClick={this.submitName}
            className='btn btn--primary btn--md'>
            <span>{contentStrings.displayNameModal.button}</span>
          </button>
          <p>{contentStrings.displayNameModal.cancel}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default DisplayNameModal
```

Comment: You didn't call state properly. Change your piece of code with this snippet. <DisplayNameModal config={this.config} displayName={this.state.displayName} />

Comment: @IhorLavs - I am now passing the displayName with `this.state.displayname`, but how do I use it in the child component?

Comment: in your child component you just call it like this.props.displayName.

Comment: @IhorLavs - hmm, that's how I already have it set `<input type="text" placeholder={this.props.displayName}/>` but it doesn't show in the input field.

Comment: Is any errors in console?

Comment: @Matt did you find the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that adding `displayName: userData.body.displayName` to `setState` and then wrapping the component in the parent with

```
{this.state.displayName &&
   <div>
    <DisplayNameModal
      config={this.config}
      displayName={this.state.displayName} />
   </div>
}
```

works as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The prop should be passed by:

```
<DisplayNameModal
      config={this.config}
      displayName={this.state.displayName} />
```

where you are using:

```
<DisplayNameModal
      config={this.config}
      displayName={this.displayName} />
```

You have set the displayName on state in the parent, anything you refer to from state should be referred to as `this.state.foo`, where as any method on that component can be referred to as `this.foo`.

Comment: I have the parent passing the displayName as state, but how is it received by the child component?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you fetch the data in wrong way, [you can check it here](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#-get-requests):

```
componentDidMount () {
  superagent.get(`/api/user`).then(res => this.setState({ user: res.body }))
}
```

the second one, initialize default state for displayName, for example, an empty string, it will be replaced when promise retrieves data data from the server:

```
constructor (props){
  super(props)
    this.state = {
    displayName: ''
  }
}
```

and pass this state as props to your child component:

```
render () {
    return (
      <div className='reviews-container'>
        <ReviewForm
          config={this.config} />

        <ReviewList
          reviews={reviews}
          ratingIcon={this.ratingIcon}
        />
        <DisplayNameModal
          config={this.config}
          displayName={this.props.displayName} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

in your child component, you can simply call this props:

```
<input type="text" placeholder={this.props.displayName}/>
```